# Which certificate to use for Google maps android api?

Tags: android, google-maps, ssl, certificate, google-maps-android-api-2

In the documentation, they only stated "first ensure that you are using the right certificate". How am I supposed to know which certificate I should use? The 2 certificates are the debug and release certificates, and I am rather confused over this part. The SHA-1 fingerprint is required to generate a key for my map. This is the link to the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

Comment: you can use the debug or the release certificates sha-1, you can change them in the console too if you use the debug and would like to switch to the release

Comment: @JRowan I have no idea what it means. What is meant by debug and release? So you meant I use the debug cert when testing the app and release cert when releasing the app onto the store?

Comment: yes the keystore file, there is a debug one typically used for development and testing, and then a release keystore that you make to sign your app for releasing to play store

Comment: your compiler should automatically use the debug keystore while you are developing your app and you have to make a release keystore through the console to sign your app when it is finished

Comment: @JRowan How do I test whether the release keystore is working?

Comment: you would know if you signed your app with the release keystore, but if your using maps and you put the SHA-1 from your release keystore and signed your app with the release keystore then the maps would work, also you cant put an app signed with a debug keystore on the market

Comment: @zbz.lvlv  While using Release keystore and want to check whether it is working or not, then just export your APK and then test it.

Answer (score 0):

During debugging and development phase you can use your debug certificate for google maps. The sha1 fingerpring of debug certificate can be found in **Window->Preferences->Android->Build**. When you are ready to export your app to play store then you will need a release certificate. The sha1 is shown during the export process.

Comment: Since you only get the export certificate during the export process how to add it to the code?

Comment: @zbz.lvlv the sha1 hash willnot change during multiple exports using same keystore so you can change the maps api key after first export.